# How do I increase the resolution of a laptop screen more than it supports?

Tags: laptop, display, resolution, gpu

I have a laptop, which has a screen resolution of 1366x768, as most laptops have. Is there any way to increase it? The laptop is an [HP Pavilion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Pavilion_(computer)) dv6, with Intel HD 3000 graphics and Radeon HD 6490M GPU.

I want to increase the resolution beyond 1366 x 768, as I have a application that requests that, and I want to run the application on this laptop only. The application requests a resolution of 1280 x 900 or higher.

Comment: By getting a higher resolution screen...

Comment: what os you use, windows or ubuntu (linux)

Comment: .. on a laptop?? I mean that is there any hack to it, maybe just virtually increase it and not really.

Comment: Windows and Ubunut both..

Comment: that's ok, you can edit your comment; there's no need to make corrections in the new comments
how about the version ? Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: It very much depends on the maximum resolution of your screen, you cannot suddenly create more pixels on your screen. Most likely your machine is detecting the correct upper limit on your resolution.

Comment: So am I right that you are asking about increasing desktop size so it will have greater dimensions (in pixels) than display itself, and maybe you want it to be scrollable too?

Comment: Version Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, My screen has max 1366X768 and I want to increase the resolution internally, I know the max this screen can populate is 1366X768 so increse then scale internally to 1366X768

Comment: VirMatrix: It sounds like you either are confused about resolution in general or using the wrong term. Give an answer to _why_ you want to increase the resolution beyond 1366x768, and people will be able to help you better.

Comment: Use external monitor temporarily. You can simply switch to only external monitor and use its native resolution.

Comment: I am doing just that for now.

Comment: "Intel HD 3000 graphics and Radeon HD 6490M GPU" -- so which is it? Both are graphics processors with way more capability than 1366X768.  The Raedon maxes at 2560x1600, the Intel at 1920x1080.  Since you didn't give the specific DV6 model i can't guess what display is in it, but I would guess it will support a much greater resolution.

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes increasing resolution is useful (even though it does reduce quality). If a dialog's height is hard-coded to 800px it'll be off the bottom of the screen, and there's very little way to see it. On a 1366x768 monitor it's less of an issue, but on a 1024x600 netbook I hit this issue all the time. Maybe you have a higher resolution external monitor and you want windows to appear the same physical size on both screens - there are lots of reasons.

You can change the resolution to above native res on Linux using the following command:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --scale 1.25x1.25
```

I find that a scale of 1.25 is on the edge of usability, probably 1.2 is more sensible. On your laptop, the output name may be different - but a quick google for XRandr will show you how to use it.

Having said that - the command worked perfectly on my Ubuntu 10.04-based netbook, but for me, on 12.04 (with gnome-panel) it changes the resolution but the mouse is still locked to the old area of the screen. It appears to be a regression, and there is a fix below so hopefully it will be fixed soon:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/883319

Comment: This is something even better, I will try it as soon as possible. But I want the fix to the bug present, please update the answer with the solution to bug as soon as possible, but a nice answer, upvoted.

Comment: Ok, its good, BUT Please suggest something for WINDOWS also, similar to this.

Comment: Thanks for this - I was just browsing, and using it in the opposite direction ( scale 0.85x0.85) makes my tinsy winsy 1920x1080 display a lot more readable next to my large external display !

Answer (score 4):

Use the `xrandr` command.
For example:
My native res is 1680×1050.

If I type in terminal:

```
xrandr --output LVDS --panning 1920x1200 --scale 1.1428571429x1.1428571429
```

I will get perfectly good 1920×1200 resolution (it's 16:10, as my screen is) but, as an earlier answer suggested, this creates an oversized desktop. I need to pan around because the whole screen cannot be shown at once, you just don't have enough pixels, that's why it's your max res. scale # you get by dividing your desired res with current res (for me 1920/1680 therefore 1.1428571429).

If you wanted full HD (e.g., 1920×1080 for your 16:9 display) you'd type in terminal:

```
xrandr --output LVDS --panning 1920x1080 --scale 1.4055636896x1.4055636896
```

We got your scale by dividing 1920 (desired) by 1366 (current/native).
If LVDS doesn't work then try LVDS1 or type `xrandr` and see which one is connected. Could be VGA1 or CRT, but if it's laptop it's most likely LVDS or LVDS1.

Comment: I cleaned up your answer. Please verify that I didn’t change the meaning.

Comment: What is `xrandr`? Does it come with the system? *What system?* The user says he uses both Windows and Ubuntu. If `xrandr` doesn’t come with the system, where does one get it?

Comment: This worked great for my laptop after searching for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It would not make sense to increase output resolution more than the screen is capable of displaying.

In best case it would have to rescale the output back to its native resolution (it *must* show is using a fixed number of pixels), which would require processing power and give you a worse result than just using the native resolution (most likely [1366x768](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_display_resolutions#WXGA_.281280.C3.97768.29), not 1399) due to interpolation errors.

In worst case it would just fail and not give you an image at all.

Sometimes it makes sense to send a resolution *lower* than the native resolution, e.g. for games where the graphics adapter doesn't have the power to render it smoothly at the native resolution, and use interpolation to show it on the full screen, but this should be avoided.

---

For completeness: to increase the resolution on your laptop you would have to buy a new laptop panel that is compatible. This is most likely not available, unless you are in real luck and your laptop is part of a series where a higher resolution model is available. It would still be a bit of a gamble to find a new panel unless you can find trustworthy verification of the specific panel model working with your specific laptop model.

---

If this is not what you mean by your question, you need to clarify.

Comment: Simply some more.. Scale it to higher resolution, similar to what done here http://superuser.com/a/468160/132745 but on Windows also

Answer (score 2):

One possible way around that could be to use what is refered to as a Oversized Desktop.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_desktop#Oversized_Desktops):

> [Oversized desktops] make it possible to pan around a desktop that is
>   larger than the available hardware is capable of displaying. This
>   facility is sometimes referred to as panning, scrolling desktops or
>   viewport.

Although not free, you could try the trial of [GiMeSpace](https://sites.google.com/site/gimespace/) to at least see if your application would work with such as tool.

I'm pretty sure that some old video drivers (ATI, NVIDIA) used to support this feature natively years ago, but I can't seem to find anything about it anymore. :/

Comment: That link to GiMeSpace is for a web site on [Google Sites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Sites) (which is fine for small non-commercial websites, but perhaps not for something containing executable content). They now have their own domain, http://www.gimespace.com/, though, but how credible are they really? They can't even spell Windows (the operating system) correctly and uses "M$" for Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Try QRes on Windows

[Qres](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/QRes.shtml)

It works on command line

```
QRes.exe /X:1024 /Y:768
```

Comment: QRes won't exceed the highest resolution registered (typically the native resolution): Error: The graphics mode is not supported!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm) to force it into a higher resolution than supported. However, forcing an incompatible resolution may be harmful to your display, graphics card, or any other component in the way.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your model, some models allow an oversized desktop, but everything starts looking like tunnel, as you need to pan around. Oversized desktops might not let some oversized desktop sensitive applications to open.

Some oversized resolution of an FHD display might me 1152 pixels or 1440 pixels, but setting these resolutions might show the entire screen, depending on your model, whether it has 'auxiliary' pixels, make a tunnel, lower the color depth, show blurry letters, or even turn black and go dead in the worst cases of very oversized desktop sensitive desktop monitors.

I suggest not trying this unless you know that is is true non-oversized desktop sensitive monitors or true very oversized desktop-sensitive monitors. All monitors have the option to hide modes that monitor can't display properly or not. In that case, when a monitor can't display properly, it is the GPU to show the picture which might look poor, depending on how sensitive your monitor is to an oversized desktop.

In that case, you must call the computer model maker to see if it's sensitive to an oversized desktop or not.

Comment: This appears to be a comment to a 3 year old question.  Comments belong in the comment section, if you cannot submit comments, you should not submit them as answers.  Answers like this are subject to removal, and based on your current answer history, its very likely you won't be able to submit new answers in the future.  The system for quality reasons, will eventual ban you automatically from submitting answers, if you continue to submit answers like this.  Once this happens it cannot be reversed by anyone.

Comment: But this has over 600 characters! How am I supposed to put it as a comment?

Comment: **Don't post comments.** You have not earned the privileged.

Answer (score -3):

The solution that worked for me was to increase my resolution size to 1366 x 766, by going to Control Panel & then Display.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The questioner wants to know if he can increase his resolution **beyond** 1366x768.